# Zip Code Boundaries Using Google Maps Api

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I need to display google map with zip code boundaries like this

http://maps.huge.info/zip.htm

Perhaps I am overlooking it, but I've not been to find examples of this and documentation talking about this specifically at Google Maps API documentation. I've trying doing a view source on the above web page link, but it doesn't seem obvious to me how it works. There is also other stuff on the page which I don't know if it's part of what I need or not.

Some simple code examples would be very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Maps API will not provide you with this data. You need an external source. <del>A Fusion Table could be of some help. You can check [this one](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1Lae-86jeUDLmA6-8APDDqazlTOy1GsTXh28DAkw#rows:id=1)</del> *.

You then need to create your own layers from the KML data that is in the table. There is [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers) about it.

<del>You can render the data directly from the Fusion Table or import it to your own database, which is often preferable for performance.</del>

Hope this helps to get you started. Try to find your way and if you are stuck, then ask another question and show us your code as the first comment suggests.

* *FusionTables was discontinued on 3 December 2019.*

Comment: after drawing boundaries, can we draw polygons and markers on that boundary

Comment: When I say *create your own layers from the KML* that is creating polygons for the given boundaries. What is your question about markers?

Comment: ohh that means we show boundaries using polygon and we can't draw one polygon in another polygon??

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve. Yes you can draw the boundaries using a polygon. Now why would you need another polygon inside? No idea. But if you need to, you can.

Comment: Yes you can but keep in mind that: If you need to add markers on map click over your polygons, you will need to disable polygon click events. You can't have both together. Adding a marker dynamically over a polygon is not an issue though.

Comment: how to add marker dynamically actually i want to show marker loaded with the polygon so can u share any links

Comment: A marker for what? And where? You need to be more explicit. If you want a marker for each postal code, you will need to calculate a center point where to add the marker. Or you can get rid of the marker and have a click event to show the details on the polygon directly, as done on the example page you mentioned.

Comment: in our project we are using kml file for generating polygon and we get coordinates from database so i want to add one more place mark at one of the coordintes but when i do this the polygon disappears and we can't see anything on map

Comment: polygonGeom = new google.maps.Polygon({
       paths:points,
strokeColor : style.fillcolor,
strokeOpacity : style.fillopacity,
strokeWeight : 3,
fillColor : style.fillcolor,                              fillOpacity : style.fillopacity
});

Comment: above is my code to add polygon, points is the array in which i get coordinates so to one of these coordinates i want to add marker so in position of marker what value should i give

Comment: I don't know the structure of your data. You should paste code in the original question. That's more readable. You need to create a `new google.maps.Marker(LatLng);` where LatLng is a `google.maps.LatLng();` object. Please check the documentation.

Comment: is it possible to display custom polygons on top of zip code boundaries displayed using Fusion Tables

Comment: i am able to display it now i want to know that can we remove fill color of polygon

Comment: Sorry but what about having a look at the [Maps API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#PolygonOptions)? Check `fillOpacity` - I think it is quite self-explanatory what these properties will do...

Comment: i am able to displlay the boundaries thanks!!! now there is one more task, i have to show one sequence no on polygon so that i can differentiate between multiple polygons, any suggestion for this?

Answer (score 14):

If anyone still looking for the solution here is how I managed to draw boundaries.

1. Download zip file from http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2014/ZCTA5/tl_2014_us_zcta510.zip (its around 500mb)
2. Unzip it, u need the shp file from the extracted files
3. On windows u need to install QGIS, to get the ogr2ogr utility
4. Run the command to get geoJSON file from shp file:

   ```
   ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" -lco COORDINATE_PRECISION=4 -simplify 0.00010 zipRegions.json tl_2014_us_zcta510.shp
   ```

   You can play with simplify to remove extra points and compress your data
5. Create free account on cartodb
6. Upload zipRegions.json file there
7. Now using cartodb.js file you can draw zip code regions on google maps easily

Simply by code like this

```
var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.1038846,-72.5868353),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),  mapOptions);

            cartodb.createLayer(map, {
               user_name: 'your_user_name',
                type: 'cartodb',
              sublayers: [
                {
                    sql: "SELECT * FROM cartodb1",
                    cartocss: '#cartodb1 {polygon-fill: #7bd490;polygon-opacity: 0.7;line-color: #6da57a;line-width: 0.5;line-opacity: 1;}'
                }
            ]})
            .addTo(map, 0) // add the layer to our map which already contains 1 sublayer
            .done(function(layer) {
                console.log('Fine');
            })
            .error(function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
```

Comment: Note that in that github link, you are pointed to links for the 2010 census, while the one above is the 2014 census.

Answer (score 2):

Working on the same thing and found boundaries-io way too expensive for our use case.

Check out https://www.maptechnica.com/

- Much larger data set
- Much more affordable

Comment: They shut down unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

I parsed the 2016 census kml file (over 150MB) to over 32,000 individual kml files you can use as a kml layer for your maps.
I put a zip file here:
https://github.com/tomeralmog/zipcode-kml
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

A Very Simply API exists for this query by zipcode,city,etc.. returns geoJson

http://www.boundaries-io.com

Image of the results in GooleMap:
[image]

Comment: Is demo version available for http://www.boundaries-io.com which would be free of cost for testing purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a relatively old question and @tomer-almog has done some great work making KML files, but I stumbled on this free resource (no relation, just using the data) that has zip code data in verious geo formats (GeoJSON, KML, etc)

https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/us-zip-code-latitude-and-longitude/table/

Might be usefull for someone....