# how to create google zipcode boundry map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to add a zip code on the map.
I am unable to find any solution for this problem.
I googled and didn't find a solution.

Please help me out.
I'm stuck with this problem.

Comment: Do you have any code to show us or an error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to modify and add on to it, but seems like you can use the following solution: [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297117/zip-code-boundaries-using-google-maps-api)